# Is it's possible to have multiple StreamBuilder in one Widget?

Tags: flutter

Is it's possible to have multiple `StreamBuilder` in one Widget?

I have got follow Widget:

```
class BuilderLoading extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TenderApiProvider apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);
    // apiProv.getToken();    
    return StreamBuilder<ApiKeyLoadingState>(
        stream: apiProv.streamApiKeyController.stream, // here
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ApiKeyLoadingState> snapshot)
        {
          switch (apiProv.apiKeyLoadingState) {               
            case ApiKeyLoadingState.Progress:
                return Text("Retreiving key");
            case ApiKeyLoadingState.Done:
                return HomePage();
            case ApiKeyLoadingState.Error:
                return Text("Key Got Error");
              break;
            default:
              return Text("Unknown");
          }

        }

    );

  }
}
```

Here I am checking for `streamApiKeyController`. But I would like to display in this widget status of another Streams. Like:
`streamApiKeyController`, `streamRegionsLoadingController`, `streamIndustryLoadingController`. How I can do it?

I mean something like:

```
return (
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ApiKeyLoadingState> snapshot)
{
   // ... streamApiKeyController

}

builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<regionsLoadingState> snapshot)
{
   // ... streamRegionsLoadingController
}
);
```

To get list:

Retreiving key

RegionsLoading

Answer (score 1):

You can nest `StreamBuilder` like this by simply returning another `StreamBuilder` with your second stream from the first's builder:

```dart
class BuilderLoading extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TenderApiProvider apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);
    // apiProv.getToken();    
    return StreamBuilder<ApiKeyLoadingState>(
        stream: apiProv.streamApiKeyController.stream, // here
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ApiKeyLoadingState> apiKeySnapshot)
        {
          return StreamBuilder<regionsLoadingState>(
            stream: streamRegionsLoadingController,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnaptshot<regionsLoadingState> regioSnapshot)
            {
               if (!regioSnapshot.hasData) return Text("Regiodata not loaded");
               switch (apiProv.apiKeyLoadingState) {               
                 case ApiKeyLoadingState.Progress:
                  return Text("Retreiving key");
                 case ApiKeyLoadingState.Done:
                  return HomePage();
                 case ApiKeyLoadingState.Error:
                   return Text("Key Got Error");
                 default:
                   return Text("Unknown");
               }
            } 
          );
        }

    );

  }
}
```

Of course you need to define your own custom logic inside the inner builder, I've just added some "dummy" logic for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

u can nest StreamBuilders:

```dart
class BuilderLoading extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TenderApiProvider apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);
    // apiProv.getToken();    
    return StreamBuilder<ApiKeyLoadingState>(
        stream: apiProv.streamApiKeyController.stream, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ApiKeyLoadingState> snapshotAPIKey){
              return StreamBuilder<ApiKeyLoadingState>(
              stream: streamRegionsLoadingController,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ApiKeyLoadingState> snapshotRegionsLoading)
            { 
            /// Do Stuff here
          }
         );
        }
     );
  }
}
```